searchDelay parameter not working in DataTables.net
I am using server side processing in datatables.net. Trying to do search using out of the box search text box. As soon as I start typing, it sends a request to controller.
I gave searchDelay of 2000ms but still it immediately sends request as soon as key is pressed.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchDelay
Here's my code:
"bServerSide": true,
"bProcessing": true,
"bSearchable": true,
"pageLength": 10,
"order": [[1, 'asc']],
"searchDelay": 2000,

How can I send search request only when user has typed 3 chars?

Perhaps you can refer to the Example in DataTable.util.debounce(). When the input value's length >= 3, then trigger the search function.

Besides, it would be great if you could provide which DataTables version that you used.
